# ClearInterval not within scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I am trying to clear and setInterval conditionally. However, when I do this, it appears the clearInterval can't see the setInterval.

When I move the clear interval out of the if statement, it works but now can no longer clear the set interval conditionally. What am I missing here?

```
// Called when user clicks on menu item
const loadQueueStatus = async () => {
  // This function will fetch queueStatus data
  const queueStatus = async () => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    const queueStatus = await getQueueStatus().then((data) => {
      this.setState({queueStatus: data})
    });
  }

  console.log("state is: ", this.state.isVolunteerStatusOpen)
  // call the queue right away if the menu just opened, we know if it is opened as state would still say false
  // We do this so we don't wait 5 seconds for the first fetch.
  if(!this.state.isVolunteerStatusOpen) {
    queueStatus()
  }

  //Set a listener, to pole the data while menu is open
  let setListener = setInterval( queueStatus, 5000);
  // If the menu is closed, the state will be true, if so, clear the listener
  if(this.state.isVolunteerStatusOpen) {
    console.log("clearing listener")
    clearInterval(setListener);
  }
  // Extra caution to clear listener
  setListener = null

  // Inform state of status window status for next click
  this.setState({
  isVolunteerStatusOpen: !this.state.isVolunteerStatusOpen
  })
}
```

Comment: the example doesn't show the issue. please may you make sure the code is a [mcve]?

Comment: apologies, I don't understand. This is the issue. If I were to run this, the setInteral won't stop, and it will keep running the function queueStatus.

Comment: We cannot replicate the issue you’ve described from the code provided. So it makes it much harder to help

Comment: Ok, I added the entire block.

Comment: apologies, after carefully reading the code I see the issue. By the time I clear the interval, I have already created a new listener. Back to the drawing board

Answer (score 0):

In my code above I was creating a new setInterval function before I cleared it. However, the real issue was that every time setInterval is set, a new ID for that setInterval is created. Even though you store setInterval in a variable, each time you create the setInterval you get a new ID and lose reference to the old one which **still exist in memory**.

To combat this, at the end of my code where I set state, I pass the variable which is equal to the setInterval to the state. So if the variable equaled **33**, this was passed to state. When I clear interval, I reference this ID in state.

```
// Called when user clicks on menu item
const loadQueueStatus = async () => {
  // This function will fetch queueStatus data
  const queueStatus = async () => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    const queueStatus = await getQueueStatus().then((data) => {
      this.setState({queueStatus: data})
    });
  }

  // call the queue right away if the menu just opened, we know if it is opened as state would still say false
  // We do this so we don't wait 5 seconds for the first fetch.
  let setIntervalFunction
  if(!this.state.isVolunteerStatusOpen) {
    queueStatus()
    setIntervalFunction = setInterval( queueStatus, 5000);
  }

  console.log(setIntervalFunction)

  //Set a listener, to pole the data while menu is open
  
  // If the menu is closed, the state will be true, if so, clear the listener
  if(this.state.isVolunteerStatusOpen) {
    console.log("clearing listener")
    clearInterval(this.state.setIntervalFunction);
  }

  // Inform state of status window status for next click
  this.setState({
  isVolunteerStatusOpen: !this.state.isVolunteerStatusOpen,
  setIntervalFunction: setIntervalFunction //Stores reference to setInterval so it can be cleared next time function is called.
  })
}
```